# Is it possible to export data directly from R to ODF?

Tags: r, export, data-processing, odf, odfweave

I know there is odfWeave. But as far as I know, odfWeave expects you to have your code **in** the OpenOffice file and R will then process that file.

**Is there a way to export directly from R to an ODF file?**

The idea is to generate an ODF file from R that includes tables, plots and basically any output in the sequence in which they are found in the R source file.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want? do you want to generate a table of coefficients, or a data table, or ... ?

Comment: added some more explanation, but the question is whether this is generally possible.

Comment: this can be done via `knitr::tangle` and `knitr::pandoc`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/formats.html) project. For example:

[image: RMarkdown CheatSheet]

> To create an OpenDocument Text (ODT) document from R Markdown you specify the odt_document output format in the front-matter of your document:

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: odt_document
---
```

**References**

- [RMarkdown: ODT Document Format](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/odt_document_format.html)
- [Dynamic Documents for R](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown)
- [OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument) TC](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office)